# Validate very long text

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table with description column. Description has a datatype text (but I tried to change to longText type into phpmyadmin). I have a validation rule too:

```
   public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|string|between:6,50',
            'city' => 'required|integer|exists:cities,id',
            'phone' => 'required_without:mail|digits:9',
            'mail' => 'nullable|required_without:phone|email',
            'description' => 'required|string|between:30,600',
            'file' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:3000'
        ];
    }
```

And it works but the problem is that if I write a very long text, I don't receive any error instead just refresh only. I had the same with other controllers method. How I can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you already made a rule, and validate it in Controller, you need to make condition if the validator fails, you need to return the error to the view. You can follow code below

```
$validator = Validator::make($request, $rule);
```

After that check the validator with

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

In your view, just show the error with

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The page refreshes because of the form's submission.

As for the validation check, 
There are 3 main types of validation -
1. Browser validation
2. Front-end validation
3. Server-side validation

The errors that you have seen in other fields of the form are probably because of the **Browser validation**. It's built into the browser.
However, with your current implementation, it is **Server-side validation**.
It will work on the background, but will not show in the front end.

For that, please add the following code inside the **body** of your html page.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also please add the following function to your validatior's Request class.

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'description.between' => "Description should be between 30 and 600 characters",
    ];
}
```

Comment: I know that form is submitted but it it would display an error and siaplay @old() data. I found where is problem but I don't know how I can solve it. So if I have this simple rule `'description' => 'required|string'` it works. Problem is if I want to validate length of string like in main post. I tryed display all errors but anything displayed.

Comment: @FamillyFriendly88943 Hi! I see. Did you add a validation error message? I just added another line of code to my answer. Can you please check it?

Comment: If that doesn't work, another option is to try - 
` 'description'   => 'required | min:30 | max: 600', `
This also works.

Comment: Yes. I add error message. Interestingly this error is display correctly. For example - if text length is 700 characters, it display error, if length is 1300 characters it doesn't display any error. 
I tryed another option before.